# discord.py sending messages in on_ready not working

Tags: discord.py

my code is:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():

   await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Farming A Fertile Land"))

   channel = client.get_channel("718204421619581063")
   await channel.send("Hi! I'm back online 。.:☆*:･'(*⌒―⌒*)))")
```

and I'm getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Answer (score 0):

Use `channel = client.get_channel(718204421619581063)` instead. In discord.py rewrite all ids are integers and not strings.

Comment: ok tysm!! i thought i did everything right but i missed that :)